# how to change the space in between blocks in drupal 6

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I don't have too much experience in Drupal or asking questions here, so I'm not sure if this question was already answered. But I would like to know how to change (increase/decrease) the space in between blocks in Drupal.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward way is to use CSS.

1. While viewing the web page with the block on it, use Firebug or Inspect Element to find the id or class of the block.
2. Add a margin to that id/class in your CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand your problem.

1. Blocks are placed in regions. Regions are defined in the html.  It follows the spacing will be defined in the CSS that governs the regions html.
2. You are using Drupal 6. I wouldn't overinvest and it now obsolete. Time to move on to Drupal 7.
3. As a hack, you can try inserting blank spaces into your blocks. If there is a WYSWYG editor set up, you can use a tab?  Dreadful hack but as you have to move on anyway?

I hope this helps. If not, forgive me.

Answer (score 0):

open block tpl files of more tpl file with **notepad++** and select **Encoding->encoding in utf-8 without BOM** and save file. 
check again.